# Docker volume file is not synced with local Spring Boot app logs file

Tags: spring-boot, docker, logging, volume

I'm running a Spring Boot application locally. It saves logs to file. This file is a volume for a docker container. When the app adds new logs to the file, the file is not synced on docker. All the changes become seen in the docker container only after I stop the app.

When I change the file locally via terminal's echo command, the changes are immediately applied to file in the container. So it seems that the problem not in docker, but in Spring Boot logging.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?